# merge or melt did not work to transfer the row wise pairs to column wise in R?

Tags: r

I want to split the row wise pairs to column wise. merge or melt functions did not work.  For instance, my dataset is like,

```
dt<-data.frame(ID=c(123,125), AgeX=c(23,30), AgeY=c(46,28))
```

and the expected result will have 2 columns in this example.

```
dt<-data.frame(ID=c(123,123,125,125), AgeX=c(23,46,30, 28))
```

Comment: you said `melt` did not work (`merge` is wrong for this), how did you call it? Sometimes it's better to help you fix the code you tried.

Comment: For me, it is working correctly `melt(dt, id.var = 'ID')[-2]`